# MySQL convert separated month and year into new field

Tags: mysql, sql, date, format, data-conversion

I have two fields as month & year where month field stored the data as string format of the month in 3 characters (Apr) and year field stored the data as numeric format (2020),
Now I need to select the both of data as a new format (04-2020) like desired_column.

```
+-------+------+----------------+
| month | year | desired_column |
+-------+------+----------------+
| Apr   | 2018 | 04-2018        |
+-------+------+----------------+
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Read [Chapter 12 Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/functions.html) of the [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/) to learn what methods are available, and you will find the solution:

- Parse the month name with [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) using specifier `%b`
- Format the month as a 2-digit number with [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) using specifier `%m`
- Combine with `-` and year with [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(month, '%b'), '%m'), '-', year) AS desired_column
  FROM mytable
```

Comment: Thank you @andreas, It's expected result for me.

Answer (score -1):

According @Andreas you should to use `STR_TO_DATE` and `DATE_FPRMAT` but in liitle different way (STR_TO_DATE wot works for month only) so query may be next:

```
WITH data (`month`, `year`) as (
  select 'Jan', 2020
  union select 'Feb', 2020
  union select 'Mar', 2020
  union select 'Apr', 2020
  union select 'May', 2020
  union select 'Jun', 2020
  union select 'Jul', 2020
  union select 'Sep', 2020
  union select 'Oct', 2020
  union select 'Nov', 2020
  union select 'Dec', 2020
)
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(concat('01',month,year), '%d%b%Y'), '%m-%Y') converted_date from data;
```

Working example can be found here [SQLize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=114ba8017dac21e11941156eb2635062&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: The month-only solution in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63665814/5221149) works perfectly fine. See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/595ad5/2) for proof on MySQL 5.6. See also [comment by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63665497/mysql-convert-separated-month-and-year-into-new-field/63665814#comment112586465_63665814) saying: "it's expected result".

Comment: Sorry, @Andreas, but your code is not works on MySQL greater 5.6 (not 5.7, not 8.0) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d60ff2007cff1bf8a5573fec7c5ba118 and even if I'm not right this is not a reason to downvote working answer